Cannot compile RC file from Delphi (Error RC1107: invalid usage use RC /? for Help)
I created an empty project and added an RC file to the project via the Project Manager.
This will add the following line in my DPR file:
{$R 'VersionInfo.res' 'VersionInfo.rc'}


The project compiles, and I get a RES file.
All nice and shiny.

However, if I switch to "Windows SDK Resource Compiler":

then I get an "RC1107" error on the first line of the RC file.
Actually, if the RC file is empty, I still get the same error.

[BRCC32 Error] VersionInfo.rc(1): invalid usage; use RC /? for Help


Looks like the IDE is sending some extra parameters to rc.exe?
Update:
I checked the command line, and it seems a semicolon is missing (see the second red arrow): 

Extra info:

I can compile the RC file from the command line and I get a RES file.
The person owning the project said that I cannot use the default RC compiler (brcc) because of some reasons (does not remember which).
Some people found that if they add or remove a slash, it works, but does not apply to my case because I don't have an "include" clause in that RC file. In the post above it is mentioned that Microsoft said this is a problem with the OS, not with rc.exe.


Fix
My "Library Path" contained an empty line. While this worked fine with the standard brcc compiler, it generated the wrong command line for the Microsoft RC. More exactly, the -v parameter was missing. Here is (the relevant part of) the command line, before and after the fix:

